# Get key and value from an Object using angular 2+

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have an Object like this:

**myComponent.ts**

```
this.detailsStruct = this.newParameter.struct;
 //the value of detailsStruct is:
            //{0: "something",
            // 5: "somethingElse"}
```

where the data of detailsstruct are coming from my mongoDb and I want to have an input form that displays keys and values of my object. In the html I did something like that:

**myComponent.html**

```
<div class="form-group" *ngFor="let s of detailsStruct ; let i = index">
 <div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: 
true}"
  [(ngModel)]="s.value" placeholder="" name="{{s[i]}}">
   </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to get something from my object but what I wrote does not work.
Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Is detailsStruct  is object? paste entire detailsStruct

Comment: Yes detailsStruct is an Object structured like I described above in the comment of the myComponent.ts

Answer (score 0):

You may use this way, I hope this will help to play with your data

```
for (let obj of this.detailsStruct) {
        for (let prop of Object.keys(obj)) {
            console.log("value-" + obj[prop]);
            console.log("key-" + [prop]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The data are coming from my db so I can only get the data that are in that format

Comment: Okay, you may play with  using  loop with your first  main object and then play with key and value in second loop.

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
<div class="form-group" *ngFor="let key of objectKeys(detailsStruct) ; let i = index">
 <div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: 
true}"
  [(ngModel)]="detailsStruct[key]" placeholder="" name="{{detailsStruct[key]}}">
   </div>
</div>
```

ts:

```
objectKeys = Object.keys;
  detailsStruct = {0: "something",
            5: "somethingElse"}
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mlwpom).

Answer (score 0):

If `detailsStruct` is an object then,

```
<div class="form-group" *ngFor="let s of Object.keys(detailsStruct) ; let i = index">
 <div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: 
true}"
  [(ngModel)]="detailsStruct[s]" placeholder="" name="s{{i}}">
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this code: Link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hh82ed

```
<div class="form-group" *ngFor="let s of detailsStruct ; let i = index">
 <div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: 
true}"
  [(ngModel)]="s[i]" placeholder="" name="{{s[i]}}">
   </div>
</div>

import {AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, ViewChild,Renderer2,OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private el: ElementRef) {}
  detailsStruct=[];
  detailsStruct = [{0:"one"},{1:"two"}];
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Yes, I could be a nice staring point but I get the data from mongoDb and they are not an array of object but  an object with key and value and I want two input value per row: one for the value and one for the key. In your case I would like to have in one row "0" and "one" and in the other row "1" and "two"

Comment: Can you please show the format in which you are getting the data from mongoDB i can help you out

Comment: the value of detailsStruct is:
            {0: "something",
            5: "somethingElse"}

Comment: i think you should change the format of how you are getting data in result for ease of  access